How do I fit a complex function to an array of values?
I have collected experimental data and have been instructed to perform a fit using a complex chirp function of the following form:
def func_M(x, a, x0, tau_p,b):
    return a*np.exp(-2*np.log(2)*(x-x0)**2/tau_p**2 + b*1j*(x-x0)**2)

Here, 'b' is a parameter to manipulate in the fitting function. I am attempting to use curve_fit from scipy.optimize, as well as the parameters x, a, x0, and tau_p. I want b to be another regular parameter.
As expected, I am encountering difficulties due to the presence of complex numbers in the function to be fitted. Do you happen to know how to fit a complex function (only the real part) to a set of real values?

Please add the dataset as a link (no screenshot)

Is you data also a sequence of complex numbers? Otherwise you probably want to return just the real part of your complex expression. You might want to plot it on the same axes as your raw data and also the residuals after fitting (always good practice).

Usually no data, no answer.

You can extract the real part of the function using np.real.
Lets say you have the following dataset:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize

def model(x, a, x0, tau_p, b):
    return np.real(a * np.exp(-2. * np.log(2.) * (x-x0) ** 2 / tau_p ** 2 + b * 1j * (x-x0) ** 2))

np.random.seed(12345)
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 500)
p = (2., 0.5, 5., 3.)
y = model(x, *p)
s = 0.1 * np.ones_like(x)
n = s * np.random.normal(size=s.size)
yn = y + n

For this setup there is not convergence issue due to oscillation:
popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(model, x, yn)
# array([2.00348614, 0.49981811, 5.00040113, 3.0020764 ])

Which renders as follow:

